# Getting error in VB.Net when using INNER JOIN with insert and update together

Tags: mysql, .net, vb.net

I'm trying to INSERT and UPDATE using INNER JOIN but whenever I save it gives me an error around SET I can't figure it out what it is really wrong with it it's my first time using INNER JOIN I really need help for this

```
mysqlConn.Open()
sqlCmd = New Odbc.OdbcCommand
sqlCmd.Connection = mysqlConn

sqlCmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO customer (guestno, datein, dateout, fullname, address, contactnum, total, paid, balance) VALUES ('" & Replace(Trim(staff_ri_txtguestno.Text), "'", "''") & "', '" & Replace(Trim(staff_ri_dtpin.Text), "'", "''") & "', '" & Replace(Trim(staff_ri_dtpout.Text), "'", "''") & "', '" & Replace(Trim(staff_ri_txtfullname.Text), "'", "''") & "', '" & Replace(Trim(staff_ri_txtaddress.Text), "'", "''") & "', '" & Replace(Trim(staff_ri_txtnumber.Text), "'", "''") & "', '" & Replace(Trim(staff_ri_txttotal.Text), "'", "''") & "', '" & Replace(Trim(staff_ri_txtpaid.Text), "'", "''") & "', '" & Replace(Trim(staff_ri_txtbalance.Text), "'", "''") & "')
SET room.customer_id = customer.customer_id
UPDATE room SET roomstatus = '" & Replace(Trim("Occupied"), "'", "''") & "'
FROM room T1 INNER Join customer T2 ON T1.customer_id = T2.customer_id
WHERE room_id ='" & staff_lblid.Text & "'"
dr = sqlCmd.ExecuteReader

mysqlConn.Close()
```

My database structure

Table name: room

room_id | roomnum | roomstatus | roomtype | rate | customer_id

Table name: customer

customer_id | guestno | datein | dateout | fullname | address | contactnum | total | paid | balance

[Here's the error Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iPhc1.jpg)

Comment: what does the error say ? have you checked that all those replace trim are correctly enclosed in single quotes when needed ?

Comment: i added some screenshot error

Comment: please see the current answer and mark it as "answer" and upvote it if possible

Answer (score 2):

Breaking down your code and Sql statement, what you are asking `MySql` to do is:

1. INSERT new customer ... - This looks OK
2. SET Customer Id on the Room table ... - This is not valid Sql
3. UPDATE Room status ... - This looks OK.

Couple this with how your generating your Sql statements it is understandable that you are having issues.

What I did was to rewrite your Sql using Parameters, which will help prevent many issues now and in the future, and also break down the changes to the `Customer` and `Room` tables in to two separate Sql statements that are executed at the same time.

```
Using conn As New MySqlConnection(ConnectionString)
    Dim insertCustomerSql As String = String.Empty
    insertCustomerSql += "INSERT INTO CUSTOMER (guestno, datein, dateout, name, address, contactnum, total, paid, balance) "
    insertCustomerSql += "VALUES (@guestNo, @dateIn, @dateOut, @name, @address, @contactNum, @total, @paid, @balance);"

    Dim updateRoomSql As String = String.Empty
    updateRoomSql += "UPDATE ROOM SET roomstatus = @roomStatus, customerid = LAST_INSERT_ID() WHERE id = @roomId;"

    Dim sql As String = insertCustomerSql + Environment.NewLine + updateRoomSql

    conn.Open()

    Using command As New MySqlCommand(sql, conn)
        command.Parameters.Add("guestNo", MySqlDbType.String).Value = 101
        command.Parameters.Add("dateIn", MySqlDbType.Date).Value = DateTime.Now.Date
        command.Parameters.Add("dateOut", MySqlDbType.Date).Value = DateTime.Now.Date.AddDays(5)
        command.Parameters.Add("name", MySqlDbType.String).Value = "JayV"
        command.Parameters.Add("address", MySqlDbType.String).Value = "My Home, England"
        command.Parameters.Add("contactNum", MySqlDbType.String).Value = "+44 1234 5678"
        command.Parameters.Add("total", MySqlDbType.Decimal).Value = 500
        command.Parameters.Add("paid", MySqlDbType.Decimal).Value = 350
        command.Parameters.Add("balance", MySqlDbType.Decimal).Value = 150

        command.Parameters.Add("roomStatus", MySqlDbType.String).Value = "Occupied"
        command.Parameters.Add("roomId", MySqlDbType.Int16).Value = 1
        command.ExecuteNonQuery()
    End Using
End Using
```

I also took the opportunity to make use of some other good practices, like the `Using` blocks.

Hope this helps you.